# Suggestions for quick GUI development tool with C++?

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder

I am looking for an RAD C++ development tool that can let me put together a not-too-complex GUI project (for video processing & display) very quickly. I would use a Active Control in the GUI, and calling some C++ libraries. I am looking at these options:

1. Visual C++. It's actually not an RAD tool, and from my past experience, MFC is really outdated and painful to use. I really don't want to touch it any more.
2. QT Creator. It's modern, elegant to use, but still not an RAD environment. I would like to work out my App in two weeks. I don't think I can do that with the QT ecosystem.
3. C++ Builder. This looks like the ideal choice. Dead easy to develop. Tons of VCL controls to easily extend the GUI functionality. But it looks like it's falling into obscurity these days (for reasons I yet to understand).

What do you think is the best choice for quick GUI development tool with C++?

(Please answer quickly since this question probably will be killed for "Off Topic" very shortly)

Comment: I live by C++Builder myself. Great tool. And a new major version, C++Builder XE4, is scheduled to be released very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Windows Forms, pretty easy with lots of help and example code.

Comment: But I need to call a C++ video library that does brutal pixel level video processing and fast video frame display. Do you think .Net can handle that?

Comment: I think vlc.net can :)

Answer (score 1):

Glade is a RAD tool to enable quick & easy development of user interfaces for the GTK+ toolkit and the GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: I agree. Glade is great. For RAD, you can use Python and PyGtk with it. In C++ you can use gtkmm. The result is a GUI application which can complie on any system supported by your build system!

Comment: Just looked at Glade. It's an interface designer only, which means my application would be developed with GTK+. From what I see so far, GTK+'s development complexity is equal to, if not more than, QT...